# Read email subject using nodemailer nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemailer

I am trying to read the subject of the email received in inbox and then use it for further work. I am using `nodemailer`(`npm` package).

I am able to send emails successfully, however unable to proceed with reading the subject of the email received.

```
const result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. nodemailer is a library for **sending** email.

If you want to read email from a mail box then you will need to determine the type of mail box it is (IMAP, POP3, Microsoft Exchange, Mailbox, mbox, etc) and select a suitable library to access it.

Alternatively, if you want to process email as it arrives you might consider configuring your incoming SMTP server to pipe mail through your script (e.g. using [procmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail)).

Comment: Can you help me with how to proceed with extracting the email subject in gmail inbox using gmail api in javscript?

Comment: [Not really](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Try reading the API documentation, having an attempt, and then asking a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) including a [mcve] if you are still stuck.